# How does TS know to reference const and not an interface

Tags: typescript

I have the following in `metadata.ts`:

```
export interface InjectableDecorator {
    (): any;
    new (): Injectable;
}

export interface Injectable {
}

export declare const Injectable: InjectableDecorator;
```

Then, I import `Injectable` into module `main.ts` and use it like this:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class ComboService {}
```

I have two questions:

1. How does TS compiler know that `Injectable` references `const Injectable` and not the `export interface Injectable`?
2. Why does `new @Injectable()` reports an eror `error TS1109: Expression expected.`, if `InjectableDecorator` allows executing the functing with `new`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The interface Injectable and the var (const in this case) Injectable are actually two distinct entities and apply in different spaces. You can also say `let number:number = 4;` When you reference Injectable as a value and not as a type, TS references the const.
2. The `@` syntax is specific to applying a decorator to a target. A new expression expects... well... an expression. Delete the `@` and call `new Injectable()` and it should work fine.

Comment: thanks, regarding the first one.. as far as I understand, although I can't use interface as a value, I still can import an interface, correct?

Comment: regarding the second one, so a decorator is a simple function, but when used with `@`, it's turned into actual decorator, correct?

Comment: 2: It's more that the function is applied as a decorator. A decorator is a function applied to a target, think of the `@` as the decorator operator

Comment: @Maximus 1. That's correct. When you imported that name, you kind of imported both the constant and the interface.